# Schema design mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have data in below format:-

```
Publisher, Network, Advertiser
P1         N1       A1
P1         N2       A1
P1         N1       A2
P2         N1       A3
```

It will not have duplicates (all three column same)

This data can grow in billions.

Query Type:-
For any given column(s) I need all values of other column(s).

Help me to design the schema in MongoDB.

Comment: can you put your query here , i am getting bit confused here with schema design , i think you need like "select * from table where publisher=P1" . but this will give you multiple result , are you expecting same from mongo ??

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb is a [schema-less database](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/119945109/why-schemaless) as such there is no schema design, you would simply store the values in a BSON object as follows:

```
{
"Publisher":"P1",
"Network":"N1",
"Advertiser":"A1"
}
```